# Cannot access to my website on ECS from outside AWS network

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, vpc

I deployed an instance(A small SpringBoot Hello World app) to AWS ECS and it's running. But, I can't access to this website from my computer. My configurations are as below :

Security Group inbound rules :

[image]

Security Group outbound rules :

[image]

Main Route table routings :

[image]

ACL inbound rules :

[image]

ACL outbound rules :

[image]

Also I'd like to note that the network type of my task definition of my service is bridge. It is a simple hello world application and there are not any probable bugs in the app and it's running. I also do have an internet gateway which is connected to the VPC of the instance. I did a reachibility analysis through the tool Amazon provides, and it tells that from that internet gateway to my instance the path is reachable. Although I cannot access my app from the browser. I had it running before. What could be going wrong? I'm really stuck here, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is the webserver configured to listen to all interfaces?

Comment: @kometen How can I do that? I mean, I haven't done any specific configuration for listeners for my app. It's a simple SpringBoot Hello World application

Comment: What address are you using when you try to connect to the service from outside the VPC? The public IP? A DNS record you have pointed to the public IP? Something else? You aren't trying to connect to the private IP, correct?

Comment: Yes definitely, I use  the Public IPv4 DNS shown on EC2 instance screen, ec2-54-79-157-118.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com here is the url I'm trying to reach.

Comment: Spring Boot binds to all known interfaces.

Comment: Could it be about outbound rules?

Comment: No, packets coming in are allowed back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access your Spring application using configured port. It would be in this format - protocol://AWS-hostname:port/spring-endpoint

Example - `http://ec2-54-79-157-118.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/hello`

Comment: That is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Edited response as per community guidelines.

Comment: Thanks a lot!, It worked, seeing the link as a url I couldn't think of adding ports.